# How to count users based on creation date table who took loan from 3 months in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

So my table USER_ID, Loan_created_date, date_opened
NOW i wanted those users who have opened loan before 3 months of Loan_created_date
For ex) if loan has been created at 22nd March then 3 months before i.e before 22nd Dec that loan has to be opened and counted as 1 for User level

data we have -

```
USER_ID  date_opened Loan_created
1        22/12/2022   23/03/2023
1        12/12/2021   12/02/2021
1        06/05/2021   07/09/2021
```

output i wanted -

```
USER_ID Count
1        2
```

Comment: Help us help you. Please add some sample data and expected output

Comment: *loan has been created at 22nd March* but loan is created 23rd March in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
# Convert as datetime64 if necessary
df['date_opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_opened'], dayfirst=True)
df['Loan_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Loan_created'], dayfirst=True)

is_before_3m = df['date_opened'] < df['Loan_created'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)
counts = is_before_3m.groupby(df['USER_ID']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
print(counts)

# Output
   USER_ID  Count
0        1      2
```

Input data:

```
>>> df
   USER_ID date_opened Loan_created
0        1  22/12/2022   23/03/2023
1        1  12/12/2021   12/02/2021
2        1  06/05/2021   07/09/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert to datetime, and a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to set 3 months before "Loan_created", then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) the boolean Series resulting from the comparison to "date_opened":

```
s = (pd.to_datetime(df['date_opened'], dayfirst=True)
       .le(pd.to_datetime(df['Loan_created'], dayfirst=True)
             .sub(pd.DateOffset(months=3)))
    )

out = s.groupby(df['USER_ID']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Output:

```
   USER_ID  Count
0        1      2
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```